# Определить образуют ли элементы массива, расположенные после последнего нулевого, убывающую последовательность

Tags: python

Дан одномерный массив числовых значений, насчитывающий N элементов. Определить образуют ли элементы массива, расположенные после последнего нулевого, убывающую последовательность.

```
import random
N = random.randint(1,10)
arr=[random.randint(-100,100) for i in range(N)]
print(arr)
k=1

for i in range(0,N):
  if arr[i]<0:
    break
  if arr[i]>=0:
    if arr[i]>arr[i+1] and arr[i+1]>=0:
      k=1
      break
    if arr[i] > arr[i+1]:
      k=2
if k==1:
  print("Нет убывающей последовательности")
elif k==2:
  print("Убывающая последовательность")
```

В этом коде определяет среди тех, которые расположены перед первым отрицательным элементом. Как переделать код по заданию?

Comment: Например, можно обходить массив с конца, пока не встретится ноль

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я добавил ноль, чтоб обязательно был :)

```
import random
N = random.randint(5,10)
arr = [random.randint(-100,100) for i in range(N-1)] +[0]
random.shuffle(arr)

k = len(arr) - arr[::-1].index(0)
arr = arr[k:]
print((len(arr) > 1) and all(arr[i] > arr[i+1] for i in range(len(arr)-1)))
```

Этот код возвращает False, если рассматриваемая последовательность состоит менее, чем из двух чисел